# Xcode restore files in bundle between unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, xctest

I'm writing a series of unit tests for a class that requires a property list stored in the bundle. I keep a mock version of this property list in my unit test target and inject the unit test bundle into the class such that it can be read. One of my unit test deals with handling the case where the file cannot be found, so I simply delete it from the bundle like so:

```
NSString *plistPath = [self.bundle pathForResource:kInAppPurchasesPlistName ofType:@"plist"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:nil];
```

However this leads to problems as the file is now deleted from the bundle, even between tests. If I set my tests up correctly this may not be an issue, but with randomized execution order it is.

I do "recreate" the bundle between unit tests:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [...]
    self.bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    [...]
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [...]
    self.bundle = nil;
    [...]
}
```

Although I'm suspecting that the underlying bundle does not change or reset state by doing this.

What's the best way of accomplishing this? In summary, I need a way that will allow me to "inject" a fake file into my class which reads it from the bundle. I want to delete this file in some tests, but for the state to be completely reset after each individual test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests should be isolated so that you can run them individually, or in any order. If a test actually deletes something, you'll have to put it back.

The danger of making changes to the file system is that it's persistent mutable state, shared across tests. Instead of talking directly to the NSFileManager, I recommend injecting it instead. Depending on your code, this could be done through an initialization parameter (preferred) or a property (second best). You can even have your production code use a lazy property so that it uses `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` by default, unless a different instance has been injected.

To inject a fake version of NSFileManager that your tests can control, I recommend using OCMockito or OCMock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon. Since I can't actually write to the bundle I will have to rewrite the class I'm testing to allow for an injected FileManager instead of Bundle. Much appreciated!